How can we get the exact aggregation of Power BI data using OpenAI in python?
We have around 2 million records in Power BI format(structured Data), which have fields like period, time, markets, region, sub-region, regional groups, product, BU(business unit), sub-BU, segments, actual_rp(revenue), forecast, budget etc.
Data is structured and create different combination within above fields.
Data Sample
User will ask in Natural language in python and once we send inputs to OpenAI it should response with aggregation as per query in summarize way.
for Example: (as per data image)
Exp 1. What is revenue for Amoxicillin? [suppose we taking period default value AP12 and time YTD]
Answer should be exact aggregation number: 4290081
Exp 2. What is forecast of Amoxile in China? [suppose we taking period default value AP12 and time YTD and if China contain in markets, region, sub-region we will printeries Market ]
Answer:  1430027 is forecast of Amoxile in China market
Since we have 2 million records, we have to care about token limit of OpenAI and other factors also.
Please share your approach for this condition, theoretically explanation also help me.
#Python #OpenAI #GenAI #PromptEngineer
We tried Conversational LLM, Vector Search but unable to get all row of records for single query. If we search for any query "Amoxicillin in China" so there is around 3K to 50k records for this combination and many more for their induvial with other combination.
So, I am unable to find way to pass records to OpenAI and get exact response for that.
Note: its working for smaller sample data records up to 100 or 1000.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
